# Auto-ARIMA command: ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (90, 11) instead

Tags: python, dataframe, arima

I'm currently trying to copy a code for my assignment:

```
stepwise_model = pm.auto_arima(df2, start_p=1, start_q=1,max_p=3, max_q=3, m=4, start_P=0, seasonal=True,
d=1, D=1, trace=True, error_action='ignore',suppress_warnings=True,stepwise=True)
```

In the assignment I have to use the above code, exept for the parameter m. I have changed the m =4, because 4 for quarterly data (which I need) In other words, use: start_p=1, start_q=1...

When I copied the code, changed into df2, I got an error:
[image: error screenshot]

Anyone can help me how I solve this error and run the auto-ARIMA command?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: In general, ARIMA only works on a 1D array. You have a 2D array. (I'm guessing that it is a pandas dataframe containing the time series you want to forecast plus some exogenous variables.) Most likely, you need to select the column you want to forecast. You haven't described what `df2` is, though, so all of that is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that y (the input data) needs to be a 1 dimensional array since ARIMA only works on 1d arrays. It looks like the problem is that df2 is a 2 dimensional array, supposing it is a pandas dataframe with a time series you should only have the values of the series in it.